# htonl, ntohl, NBO client and server

Tags: sockets, networking, byte, winsock

I  am writing server and client and i have some integers to pass.

In my server application i am recieving an integer from the client.

In the client do i call ntohl or htonl on the integer?
If i call either one of these, when i recieve the integer do i have to call ntohl or htonl again? Or do i only call ntohl/htonl on the server side, but not the client side?

In other words, when/where and how many times do i use htonl or ntohl for each integer?

Also, do i have to do ntohl/htonl for strings/chars arrays?  Does chars have to be converted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In the client do i call ntohl or htonl on the integer?

It has nothing to do with whether you are the client or the server. It has to do with whether you are sending or receiving. If you are sending, you want network byte order, so you call `htonl`(). If you are receiving, you want host order, so you call `ntohl().`

> If i call either one of these, when i recieve the integer do i have to call ntohl or htonl again?

Yes. The sender should have put the data into network byte order; the receiver has to put it into host order, for his local host.

> In other words, when/where and how many times do i use htonl or ntohl for each integer?

`htonl()` when sending; `ntohl()` when receiving.

Answer (score 1):

When sending an integer, always call `hton...()` to make sure the bytes are converted from the sending machine's native byte order into network byte order.

When reading an integer, always call `ntoh...()` to make sure the bytes are converted from network byte order into the receiving machine's native byte order.

On machine's where the native byte order is the same as network byte order, the functions are implemented as no-ops.  On machine's where the native byte order is not the same, the functions perform byte swaps.

Answer (score 0):

The typical setup in this scenario would be to call `htonl` in the client (because you want to put the integer into *network* i.e. *protocol* order) and `ntohl` in the server (because you want to convert back from network to *host* order).

There is no equivalent of `ntohl` etc for strings (although you do have to make arrangements for the client and server to agree on the character encoding used, i.e. by having both sides use UTF-8).

Comment: For strings, only UTF-16/32 encodings are affected by byte order, since they both use multi-byte codeunits.  Other UTF encodings, and all ANSI/ISO encodings, use single-byte codeunits instead.  The `hton...` and `ntoh...` functions can be used on UTF-16/32 data, just call them on a per-codeunit basis. This would only be needed when converting UTF-16/32 LittleEndian to UTF-16/32 BigEndian and vice versa.

Comment: @RemyLebeau. good point regarding UTF-16/32 strings, although this case could also be handled by prefixing the strings with a byte order mark.

Comment: It has nothing to do with client and server, only with sending and receiving.

Comment: @EJP that is true, but I was explaining in the context of the original question, where the client is the sender and the server the receiver.